# Django with eclipse

Tags: python, django, eclipse

I register URL with callback function like this `url(r'^G2S/TestList$', testList)`

and this is callback function

```
def testList(request):

    fi = open('testlist.html', 'r')
    html = fi.read()
    fi.close();    

    #html = '<html><body> <FORM ACTION="/G2S/HostReceiver" METHOD="POST"> First name: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="firstName" VALUE="J. Random"><BR>  Last name:  <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="lastName" VALUE="Hacker"><P>  <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT"></FORM> </body></html>' 
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

the problem i have suffered is when calling `open('testlist.html', 'r')` in the callback function(if i use eclipse dejango run)

django is saying `Exception Value : [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'testlist.html'`

but on the contrary, if i use command line with `python manage.py runserver`

it work normally with no the error.

the project hierarchy is like below

```
project folder    
     |       
     src folder
         |
         manage.py
         testlist.html
```

why it only makes the error with eclipse

and one more thing, why does eclipse break point on debug mode seem not working?

for example i check a break point at the callback function above(testList), and enter to

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/G2S/TestList` on debug mode, i think eclipse should stop at the point i check, though error occur, but does't, why?

Answer (score 2):

Read about how to use templates in your projects. Using file operations like that is not recommended.

Add this to your `settings.py` file

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '<app>/templates'))
```

Then add your html files to the `project/<app>/templates` folder.

Then render the templates in your view using

```
return render(request, 'testlist.html')
```